# Jquery - how to refer to the root element of the function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here I'm applying jquery's autocomplete function to all the textboxes on my page with the `main-item` class.

The problem is on the line `var search = ($this).val().toLowerCase();` I'm trying to get the text of the textbox, but here `$this` just refers to the data returned from the ajax call. How can I get the text from `$( ".main-item" )` element that invoked this function instead?

```
$(function () {
    $( ".main-item" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.test.com",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (data) {
                    var matches = [];
                    var search = ($this).val().toLowerCase();

                    $(data).find("string").each(function () {
                        var item = $(this).text();
              
                        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
                            matches.push(item);
                        }
                    });

                    response(matches);
                },
                error: function (req, err) {
                    console.log(req)
                }
            });

        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".main-item").val(ui.item.value); 
            $("span.input-group-btn > input").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle each textbox individually with `jQuery::each()` and save a texbox to a variable for later use.
And please for god's sake don't use `var`, use modern `const/let` instead...

```js
$(function () {
    $( ".main-item" ).each(function(_, textbox){
       
        const $textbox = $(textbox);

        $texbox.autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://api.test.com",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var matches = [];
                        var search = $textbox.val().toLowerCase();

                        $(data).find("string").each(function () {
                            var item = $(this).text();

                            if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1) {
                                matches.push(item);
                            }
                        });

                        response(matches);
                    },
                    error: function (req, err) {
                        console.log(req)
                    }
                });

            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $textbox.val(ui.item.value); 
                // you have a bug here maybe
                $("span.input-group-btn > input").click();
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```